# Does the flame-type influence emission spectra?

Tags: visible-light, atoms, photon-emission

I am thinking about the following question:

when I look at the atomic emission spectrum  of a specific element and I am only interested in the visible section of this spectrum and the method of retrieving it is via putting the element inside a flame, does the type of the flame in any significant way impact the observed spectrum?

For example, does it matter wheter I excite lithium with a standard propane flame or instead a hydrogen or acetylene flame?
I am trying to find ressources on this online but so far I haven't found any spectrum of any element that was measured using anything else than "the flame method" which I suspect refers to using propane gas (or other falmes with less known composition) as the exciting medium.

I was tasked to find such spectra measured using different types of flames but since I couldn't find anything on this I am wondering if this question makes sense in the first place.

Comment: (+1) The spectra definitely depend on the atom reservoir, i.e., flame, plasma, hollow cathode lamp, gas discharge tube, etc. Even in simple flames, the observed spectra depend on whether the element of interest interacts with other flame species. Calcium and strontium, for example, readily form CaOH and SrOH species in flames and these emit the typical flame emission colors. Other elements require ionization suppression additives and others form refractory oxides unless you use higher flame temperatures. Look in the atomic absorbance spectroscopy literature. Hope this helps a bit!